# How to Isolate (detour) constructor of class with Microsoft Fakes Shim?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

Is there a possibility to isolate / replace an constructor of a class with Microsoft Fakes?

In found an example for Mole (antecessor of Fakes): http://thecurlybrace.blogspot.co.at/2011/11/how-do-i-detour-mole-type-constructor.html

I tried constructs like this

```
ShimStreamReader.Constructor = @this => ShimStreamReader.ConstructorString(@this, "Test");
```

but it says the get accessor is missing. To clarify it would be nice to replace something like

```
new StreamReader("filename")
```

with static input like this

```
new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("33\r\n1\r\n16\r\n5\r\n7")))
```

so that i do not have to mock Read, ReadLine, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to replace and call a different constructor via reflection:

"Hence, when you are replacing a constructor you should do all your initialization in your constructor. For StreamReader constructor is may not be possible as you don't know how object is internally initialized by original constructor and you don't have access to private members of object.

So, we can use reflection to call in original constructor with to initialized the object and then use it." - See Vikram Agrawals answer on [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstest/thread/99edf49e-4f75-4bbe-a5e0-b788f783cb36)

So the code regarding to my question would look like this:

```
ShimStreamReader.ConstructorString = (@this, value) =>
{
    ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof (StreamReader).GetConstructor(new[] {typeof (Stream)});
    constructor.Invoke(@this, new object[] {new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("33\r\n1\r\n16\r\n5\r\n7"))});
};
```

Answer (score 6):

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    ShimStreamReader.ConstructorString = 
        delegate(StreamReader @this, string @string)
        {
            var shim = new ShimStreamReader(@this);
            shim.Read = () => 42;
        };

    var target = new StreamReader("MeaningOfLife.txt");
    Assert.AreEqual(42, target.Read());
}
```

Comment: What you want is an emulated StreamReader. That's not something we can generate. You'd have to build it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with emulated StreamReader, but it was possible detouring (or replacing) a constructor call in Moles (see sample above), and i thought it may be possible in Fakes. I tried different solutions (like putting the "new StreamReader("filename")" call into a method and replacing the whole method with "new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("33\r\n1\r\n16\r\n5\r\n7")))", but it would be more elegant todo this via Constructor Mocking / Replacing because then i do not have to alter existing code.

Comment: It is possible via reflection, see my (Vikram Agrawals) answer below.